# Запросить все контакты пользователя из mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

В mysql есть таблица: 
`id | sender | receiver | message_text | read | created_at`.

Юзер может быть `sender` - отправителем сообщения или `receiver` - получателем сообщения. Мне необходимо получить айди всех собеседников с которыми списывался пользователь, находясь в любой из обозначенных ролей.

Например:

```
id | sender  | receiver | message_text  | read | created_at
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 3       | 6        | abc demo text | 0    | 2016-02-02 10:20:20
 2 | 1       | 8        | abc demo text | 0    | 2016-02-02 12:20:20
 3 | 6       | 3        | abc demo text | 0    | 2016-02-03 12:10:20
 4 | 6       | 8        | abc demo text | 0    | 2016-02-03 12:10:33
```

Пользователь с `id=6` получал или отправлял сообщения пользователям с `id=3` и с `id=8`. На выходе я хочу получить ответ `3,8`. Как должен выглядеть запрос для такого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно к чему-то прицепится, к примеру у Вас условие:

> Пользователь с id=6 получал или отправлял сообщения пользователям с id=3 и с id=8.

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `sender` = '6' OR `receiver` = '6';
```

Мы получим: 1,3,4. Как и сказано в условии

> получить айди всех собеседников с которыми списывался пользователь, находясь в любой из обозначенных ролей

Если я не прав - поправьте, может до меня условие не дошло верно

Comment: да, это абсолютно правильный ответ. от усталости не сообразил, что делаю не так и полез в case/if